# Adding a tab between every number and letter

Tags: command-line, sed

I want to add a tab character to seperate numbers and letters of my file:

```
71aging
1420anatomical_structure_development
206anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis
19ATPase_activity
46autophagy
2634biological_process
```

So now it would look like this:

```
71  aging
1420  anatomical_structure_development
206  anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis
19  ATPase_activity
46  autophagy
2634  biological_process
```

Is there a one liner **sed** for this?

Comment: Your headline suggested this `sed -re 's/(.)/ \1/g'`, but the example did not, so I changed your headline.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot. I checked, that's not what I wanted to achieve. Do you have a solution?

Comment: You should learn some basic `sed`, the `s` command is the most common. Also learn regular expressions. This was not a hard problem.

Comment: between *every* number and letter, or just the first one (if there are any numbers in the 2nd part of the lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below one is the sed one liner for your requirement

```
 sed "s/^[0-9]*/&\t/g" filename
```

output

```
71      aging
1420    anatomical_structure_development
206     anatomical_structure_formation_involved_in_morphogenesis
19      ATPase_activity
46      autophagy
2634    biological_process
```

Comment: Is that a tab character after the `&`? You might say so explicitly, otherwise it looks like a space.

Comment: Thanks for observation i though it should be space. Corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -re 's/([0-9]+)([^0-9].*)/\1\t\2/g'
```

Find digits then non-digit and other stuff. And add a space after the digits.

Comment: I believe that it is better to use `-E` instead of `-r`.

Comment: Does regular sed have -E ?

Comment: Fine, either [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) [AIX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/sed.htm) [HPUX](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/sed.1.html) or [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/sed-1.html#scrolltoc) don't support the -E option, I guess we will have to wait a bit (years) longer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `sed`

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*/&\t/' infile
```

Comment: You know you can use `^[0-9]\+`?

Comment: Yes, I used `[0-9][0-9]*` as it's POSIXly as I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/\([0-9]\)\([A-Za-z]\)/\1${tab}\2/" < input > output
```

This searches for the first appearance of a number (0-9) followed by a letter (A-Za-z) and replaces it with (that number) followed by a tab followed by (that letter).

To omit the ${tab} variable, enter the same sed command, but replace the ${tab} with an actual tab (<kbd>Control-V</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([A-Za-z]\)/\1TAB-HERE\2/' < input > output
```

Comment: Doesn't sed (all seds) support `\t` for tab?

Comment: I happened to test on AIX, which didn't.

Answer (score -1):

With what you have as input, and [POSIX BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html):

```
sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)$/\1\t\2/g' input.txt
```

It is also sufficient to use `perl` with grouping:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+)(.*)/\1\t\2/g' input.txt
```

Comment: Well, stackexchange formatting doesn't recognize tabs: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255953/why-does-the-tab-key-not-work-while-writing-questions-answers